# Definition about locally convex space (Conway)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

I'm reading the book

> A course in Functional Analysis, John B.Conway.

A locally convex space $X$ is defined by

1. X is topological vector space
2. There exist a family $\mathcal{P}$ of seminorms on $X$ such that $\{x \in X | p(x - x_0) < \epsilon\}$ generates a topology on $X$ as a subbasis, where $x_0 \in X, \epsilon >0$ and $p \in \mathcal{P}$.
3. $\bigcap \{x \in X : p(x) = 0\} = 0$.

On the other hand, the author says that
"Sometimes it is convenient to assume that $\mathcal{P}$ consists of all continuous seminorms. The resulting topology on $X$ remains unchanged." (At the top of page 101)

My questions are the followings:

1. Why is it true? Then, is it true that TVS does not depend on collection $\mathcal{P}$?.  I think definitely not, but I can't understand what the author says.
2. If $M$ is closed linear subspace of $X$, then is it true that the infimum, inf $\{p(x+y): y \in M\}$, is attained like the case for the norm, either for $p$ is continuous or not? (I think this helps me to show the quotient space of locally convex space is locally convex)

Thank you for any helps!